# Force FACEBOOK GRAPH API to show profile url image instead download it

Tags: json, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Working with Facebook API Graph 8.0, I get a JSON with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/1234567890?fields=picture&redirect=false&access_token=my_secret_token
```

with the following content:

```
{
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 100,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1234&height=100&width=100&ext=1234&hash=abc",
      "width": 100
    }
  },
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```

but when I tried to do a

```
<img src="https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1234&height=100&width=100&ext=1234&hash=abc">
```

doesn't work, and in a browser it downloads it and not showing.

How can I use the image and/or how can i retrieve the Facebook Profile URL in order to show it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to show your image there is a much easier way to show images than querying graph api with access token and then showing the image.

you can directly use it with `<img>` tag.

just add `/picture` to the end of api call like this

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture">
```

you can also request different sizes like

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?width=360&height=900">
```

or a square thumbnail with

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?type=square">
```

for more informations check here :
[Facebook graph api v8 User Picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)
**Notice**

Facebook has two kinds of UIDs one is the original UID each user is assigned when they join facebook.com and the other is App-Scope UID each user gets when they install a facebook app. your app would always retrive App-Scope UID when calling endpoints like `/me`. the way to get original UID is either by manually collecting them with different techniques or setting a web-scraper to do so automatically.

facebook is deprecating accessing photos with `/user_id/picture` endpoint when user_id is original UID unless access_token is provided this should not bother anyone because all apps get the app Scope UID unless you are trying to debug your app and cant figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your time! mmmm what browser are you? I'm in firefox lastest version:
https://imgur.com/O1a255m

Comment: i'm using Chrome on mac

Comment: @Leandro i did test with chrome in windows and firefox in mac they both worked too. maybe you have changed a setting or something. try with another browser or a new profile.

Comment: @Leandro i did test with chrome in windows and firefox in mac they both worked too. maybe you have changed a setting or something. try with another browser or a new profile.

Comment: doesn't work - just shows a grey image